# In Salesforce, how to disable Grant Access using Role Hierarchy for Standard Object

Tags: role-hierarchy, outofbox

In Salesforce, how to disable/bypass Grant Access using Role Hierarchy for Standard Object.

We know we can't disable this option for Standard Object but how to stop role hierarchy to see the record which is not owned by them. Any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Restriction Rules? You can use it to supersede existing access rules to reduce existing access to records.

Comment: But Restriction Rules are only for Custom objects and some standard object which does not include Account, contact Standard Object and my question is for Standard object.